# Split data in different columns

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm working on CSV Excel sheet, and facing an issue with a VBA macro.

My original CSV file is looking this way : 
[image: Initial situation]

What I'm trying to do is simple, I would like to detect when there are different option in "Option1Name" and split the data (Name + Value) in the next column.

Here is the final result :
[image: Final result of the macro]

When I execute my macro, it move datas in the other column, but only on the first row :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
Sub fillHandle()
Dim i As Long
Dim optStart As Integer

'Start counting the option
 optStart = 2

 For i = 2 To 6000

 Column2 = Sheets("products").Range("I" & i).Value

 If IsEmpty(Range("H" & i)) = False Then

    If optStart <> 2 Then
        If Sheets("products").Range("I" & i - 1).Value <> Column2 Then
            Sheets("products").Range("J" & i).Value = Sheets("products").Range("H" & i).Value
            Sheets("products").Range("K" & i).Value = Column2
            Sheets("products").Range("H" & i).Value = ""
            Sheets("products").Range("I" & i).Value = ""
        End If
    End If
Else
'If option cell is blank then we set the i variable with the row of the column
optStart = i
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the problem you're facing exactly? An error message? Also without any code shown we can't help you too much.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to paste my macro..

Comment: @f1rstsurf you can go through your code step by step using F8 to find out where it goes wrong. Between each step you can check the values of your variables. Analyzing your code that way should lead you into the point where your issue is.

Comment: Your screenshot is NOT the csv file.  Rather it is a screenshot of the CSV file after you have opened it in Excel.  Better if you post (as text that can be copy/pasted) data from a sample CSV file.  Open the CSV file in a Text Editor (eg Notepad or Notepad++) and then copy/paste the text from that into your question (and format that as "code" in your question, so it will line up correctly).

Answer (score 0):

i finally succeeded, even if i guess my code could be improved :

```
Sub splitColumn()
Dim i As Long
Dim optStart As Integer
Dim OptionRowName As Integer
Dim OptionRowValue As Integer

'Start counting the option
optStart = 2
OptionRowName = 3
OptionRowValue = 4

For i = 2 To 6000

'Retrieving option Value
Column2 = Sheets("products - Copie").Range("B" & i).Value

'If Option Name is not empty
If IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) = False Then
    'If it is not the first time we loop (we don't want to move the first option of the first line)
    If i <> 2 Then
        'If Column2 and Active cell do not contains the same datas
        If Sheets("products - Copie").Range("B" & i - 1).Value <> Column2 Then
            'I'm starting to move the datas in the next columns
            Sheets("products - Copie").Range(Split(Cells(1, OptionRowName).Address, "$")(1) & optStart).Value = Sheets("products - Copie").Range("A" & i).Value
            Sheets("products - Copie").Range(Split(Cells(1, OptionRowValue).Address, "$")(1) & optStart).Value = Column2
            'Then I delete the obsolete values
            Sheets("products - Copie").Range(Split(Cells(1, 1).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value = ""
            Sheets("products - Copie").Range(Split(Cells(1, 2).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value = ""
            optStart = optStart + 1
            OptionRowName = OptionRowName + 2
        End If
    End If
Else
    'If option Name and Option Value are empty cells, it means it is a new product
    If IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) = False And IsEmpty(Range("B" & i)) = False Then
        optStart = i
    End If

    'If Option value cell is not empty and It is not the first time we loop into, it means it is a new
    'option to move
    If IsEmpty(Range("B" & i)) = False And optStart <> 2 Then
        'I'm starting to move the datas in the next columns
        Sheets("products - Copie").Range(Split(Cells(1, OptionRowValue).Address, "$")(1) & optStart).Value = Column2
        Sheets("products - Copie").Range(Split(Cells(1, 2).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value = ""
        'We decrement optStart to place the data in the right cell at next round
        optStart = optStart - 1
        OptionRowValue = OptionRowValue + 2

    End If
End If

Next i

End Sub
```